# Telerik MVC Grid - Sum error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

I am using the following line to get a column sum:

```
columns.Bound(item => item.McGross).Width(50).Title("Amount").Aggregate(aggreages => aggreages.Sum()).Format("{0:c}").FooterTemplate(result =>
            { %><%= result.Sum.Format("{0:c}") %><% });
```

I get error when any of the column valuse are null.  How can I use "if" null put "0" for that record.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good people at Telerik has provided an answer, here it is:

```
.FooterTemplate(result =>
{
  %>Total Sum: <%=
    (result.Sum == null || (double)result.Sum.Value == 0.0)
      ? "Value not available"
      : result.Sum.Format("{0:c}")
    %><%
});
```

It worked. Hope this could help someone else.

Comment: It helps but that sucks. What's the point of the NoRecordsTemplate if you have to write this much ugly code for such a likely scenario. Better and cleaner to check if the Model is empty before rending the grid.